# Connect to SharePoint web service through Claims-Based NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, ntlm, claims-based-identity

We have a SharePoint server which I can reference through the following:

```
//DCP connection
private static dcp.Lists lists = new dcp.Lists();
lists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
lists.Url = Values.SERVERADDRESS + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```

This works through a port which only has Domain authentication (`SERVERADDRESS` value `http://dcp:17649`).
However, our browser uses other authentication methods through `http://` and `https://`.
These are Claims-based and contain Forms-based authentication for external users and NTLM authentication for users on the domain.
However, I seem unable to access this through these ports.
Here's my code:

```
//create networkCredential
System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
System.Net.CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();

//add into CredentialCache and speicfy the NTLM authType
cc.Add(new Uri(Values.SERVERADDRESS + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"), "NTLM", nc);

lists.Credentials = cc;
lists.Url = Values.SERVERADDRESS + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```

the `SERVERADDRESS` value is `http://dcp` here.

There are several posts all over the internet (also here) which have something to do with changing the app.config. However, mine looks totally different than the ones you can find in these posts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DriverDevPlanning.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DriverDevPlanning.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="DriverDevPlanning_dcp_Lists" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://dcp/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DriverDevPlanning_dcp_UserGroup_UserGroup" serializeAs="String">
                 <value>http://dcp/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </DriverDevPlanning.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```